# Is there a updated Python module which I can use to communicate with a Minecraft server?

Tags: python, sockets, client, minecraft, packets

I looked up myne and mc3p, but those didn't even work with my old copy of Minecraft 1.8. If there is some module that allows me to communicate with a minecraft server as if my program was the Minecraft client. If it is available, I could settle for a module that allows you to simulate a Minecraft server and have minecraft client connect to it. I tried to implement my own using the socket module and the struct module, but I am bad at both. I have Python 2.5 with Windows XP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://www.wiki.vg/Client_List) has a list of client implementations. From that, I saw the following clients that were implemented in Python:

- [Twisted Bot](https://github.com/lukleh/TwistedBot)
- [pyCraft](https://github.com/ammaraskar/pyCraft)
- [esbot](https://github.com/espes/esbot)
- [mcclient](http://hg.sitedethib.com/mcclient/)

Keep in mind that the Minecraft server is not designed for 3rd party clients to connect to it: the client/server protocols are not an open spec that Mojang freely supports others to use. It just so happens that the Mojang doesn't typically come down hard on 3rd party mods (in fact, they [hired some 3rd party modders](http://www.minecraftforum.net/news/417-bukkit-officially-joins-mojang/)). Mojang is still in development of their official modding APIs, and so any library created now that interfaces with Minecraft can only be supported as well as the library author can reverse-engineer the Minecraft system, and keep up to date with changes in Minecraft.

Because of this, expect the libraries you find to be error-prone or have difficulties working on different versions of Minecraft.

Comment: I just tried pCraft and mcclient, and I don't think they are updated to 1.3.2. They kept giving me packet errors